# *Follow up** I'm trying to input an integer into a website box using Selenium and I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, mozilla, sendkeys

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#adds geckodriver script as selenium doesn't directly work with geckodiver anymore
ff = "C:\Python36\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe"

#opens website
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
browser.get('https://www.cookcountytreasurer.com/setsearchparameters.aspx')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,30)

#PINs into website
elementID1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPanel1_SearchByPIN1_txtPIN1']")))
elementID1.send_keys("17")
```

The cmd prompt then reads the following:

```
File "<stdin>", line2
    elementID1.send_keys("17")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what is causing the syntax error. Further help is appreciated. I fixed a number if issues in my original code based on helpful responses to my original question but I'm still getting a syntax error on the send keys.

Comment: if this is the exact code you are running, you should change `findelement` to `find_element`. Also, your xpath doesn't seem to show any element on inspection

Comment: also, it should be `By.XPATH`

Comment: also the bracket syntax incorrect,  including everything that @BibekjitSingh has advised it should be `browser.find_element(By.XPATH("//[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPanel1_SearchByPIN1_txtPIN1']")).click`

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Happy Holidays!

Comment: Could you include a link to your original question?

Comment: @WhooNo I wrote over my original question with the text above. The new code seems to work fine up until the SyntaxError on the send keys at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned there are various syntax error in the line:

```
browser.findelement(By.xpath("//[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPanel1_SearchByPIN1_txtPIN1'])").click
```

It should be something like below:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPanel1_SearchByPIN1_txtPIN1']").click()
```

And better apply some waits.

```
# Imports Required:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.cookcountytreasurer.com/setsearchparameters.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

elementID1 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPanel1_SearchByPIN1_txtPIN1']")))
elementID1.send_keys("17")
```